# Stack Overflow Jobs should have a natural language option

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

There are job posts on Stack Overflow Jobs that require a working knowledge of a natural language. I think it will be nice to have this stated as a tag, so we can sort by it. It's good for companies, too.

If you live in Europe, you will understand why this is needed.

Comment: Very good idea especially as many of the listings don't specify language requirements and I have to go by language ad posted in.